# No texture bound to the unit 0

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am currently facing an error that I cannot seem to figure out.

In chrome I am receiving:

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glTexImage2D: invalid internal_format GL_FALSE
RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0
```

Which is resulting in my 3D object having just a black texture rather than the image I have waiting to be rendered.

Comment: I removed the three.js tag from your question as apparently you are doing manual WebGL.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with this if you're not providing any code?

Answer (score 0):

`internal_format` is the 3rd argument to `gl.texImage2D`. The error mesages says you are passing either `0` or `undefined` or `null`. All of those become `0` which is the same as `GL_FALSE`.

You need to pass a valid internal format like `gl.RGBA`, `gl.RGB`, etc...

The second error is because of the first.

Answer (score -3):

So I found the answer after fiddling around with my code a little, turns out its a simple fix (maybe stupidity on my part) but what I used to have was this:

```
var boxTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, boxTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,     gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,document.getElementById('crate-image'));
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

All that needed changing was the order, so now it looks like this:

```
var boxTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, boxTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,     gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,document.getElementById('crate-image'));
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

Comment: that makes no sense. Also your error has nothing to do with lines you modified, only the `texImage2D` line. Are you sure this is where the error is?